# Python GPIO Script does not work in background

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python

I have written a script to open/close my roller shutter using two buttons and a relay. One button to open, one button to close.

Here is my script :

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

relay_pin = 18
down_button_pin = 17
up_button_pin = 27

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(relay_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(down_button_pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(up_button_pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def main():
    while True:
        # Get the state of each button (pressed or not)
        down_input_state = GPIO.input(down_button_pin)
        up_input_state = GPIO.input(up_button_pin)

        # Button is pressed
        if down_input_state == False:
            print('Button Down Pressed')
            GPIO.output(relay_pin, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(5)

        if up_input_state == False:
            print('Button Up Pressed')
            GPIO.output(relay_pin, GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(5)

try:
    main()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

When I run the script, everything is working as expected :

```
$ python button_relay.py
```

But when I try to run it in the background :

```
$ python button_relay.py &
[1] 29690
```

the script does not work anymore.

What am I missing here ?

---

> Raspberry Pi 3 Model B
>   Raspbian

General advises about my script are also welcome.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: @joan When I press buttons, nothing happen. While running in foreground, pressing buttons open/close shutters.

Comment: There is a mismatch in the script.  It will not work, you have down_pin as well as down_button_pin.

Comment: @joan Yep sorry I corrected it. But still same issue.

Comment: The script works for me  - foreground and background.  Try adding a time.sleep(0.1) in the while loop so it's not busy spinning.

Comment: @joan Thanks for helping. How long have you been testing it in background? Sometimes I works fine in background and after ~1 hour it stop working.